# Research Posters - Do you put home university logo when you did the research at another university?

Tags: research-undergraduate, affiliation, poster

I am currently doing research at a school that is not my home institution. When I create a poster board for this research, do I put logos of both the school where I am doing the research as well as my home institution? Or do I not mention my home institution at all?

If appropriate, where do I mention my home institution on this research poster?

Comment: Is your home institution currently paying you? If so, that definitely counts as supporting your research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put the logo of the funding agency (NSF, NASA, etc.) and the logo of the university where you are doing this research. If your home university isn't involved in any way, then you're probably fine excluding it.

Comment: My home university is paying for about half of the research costs, and the place where I am doing research is paying for the other half. In that case, would I include my home unversity logo? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, I would put both.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing research at that university and are funded by the other university, you should put both logos. Moreover, you should also put the logo of other funding agencies if some are involved in your project.  You may also write an acknowledgedment such as "This projected was funded by NSF grant #12345" to indicate the specific grant that funded your project. Besides, if you have co-authors from other universities, you may also put the logo of their universities. Finally, you could also decide to not put any logo, and write the university affiliations and funding information as text, and it would also be fine

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1.)It would be fine (and visually better) to have one logo. But which one? Well, it is appropriate to have the logo of the University/Institute that you are doing the research with. It is their faculty that you work with and contribute. You can then list your home university and other funding agencies in a "special thanks" section at the bottom of your poster.

2.)You don't want to even chance doing anything uncouth, so you can put all logos Oprah style. You get a logo! And you get a logo!

**Special Case: before leaving someone out be sure that there isnt anything in your contract or funding agreement that says "If I give you money, you will list my logo"**